# Spring 6 Webclient is missing Micrometer Histogram metrics

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

When I make calls using the Spring 6 webclient by autowiring the WebClient.Builder class. I dont see any metrics for the latency it took for the calls to complete. Previously, in Spring 5 webclient we had **http_client_requests_seconds_bucket** metrics with "**le**" label to create dashboards for latencies.

Spring 5 webclient was paired with micrometer v1.9.2

Spring 6 webclient seems to be using micrometer v1.10.8

How to get these metrics in Spring 6 webclient?

Comment: Spring 5 had no integration, Spring 6 has integration. So if you had them in Spring 5 you added something that added that behavior. If you still have both they might interfere (or you added something that disabled the autoconfiguration for the metrics in Spring Boot).

Comment: Spring 5 internallly adds an exchangeFilterFunction to make this instrumentation

Comment: No it does not. That is part of Spring Boot Actuator not Spring.

Answer (score 0):

If you see `http.client.requests` metrics, you already done half of the work you need to do (activated the `WebClient` instrumentation).

If you also need histogram support, you can either create a `MeterFilter` `@Bean` and enable histograms for `http.client.requests`, see the docs: https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_configuring_distribution_statistics

Or you can simply enable histograms from your config:

```
management.metrics.distribution.percentiles-histogram.http.client.requests=true
```